# Data Structure for tuple indexing

Tags: sorting, tuples, radix-sort

I need a data structure that stores tuples and would allow me to do a query like: given tuple `(x,y,z)` of integers, find the next one (an upped bound for it). By that I mean considering the natural ordering `(a,b,c)<=(d,e,f) <=> a<=d and b<=e and c<=f`. I have tried MSD radix sort, which splits items into buckets and sorts them (and does this recursively for all positions in the tuples). Does anybody have any other suggestion? Ideally I would like the abouve query to happen within O(log n) where n is the number of tuples.

Comment: If you have abc of (2,2,2) which is next upper (3,1,3) or (3,2,2) or even (2,3,3) ? Wanting to be clear on desired order.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize for not having been specific enough.
Let's say we were able to convert each tuple to the corresponding base 10 integer. Next would be the _smallest_ such integer greater than the current one. So, in your example, (2,2,2)<(2,3,3)<(3,1,3)<(3,2,2).

Comment: And by the way, converting to base 10 is out of question, in case you want to suggest something like that :), (given the potentially huge arity and our limitation to 4 or 8 bytes).

Comment: If a,b,c are all integers, say 32bit, then aren't they already useable as base 2^32? Ie you could store them as the 96bit value (a<<64)|(b<<32)|(c).  Keep that in sorted order and you are done? This doesn't use any more space than strong each int seperately, or are you wanting tree like compression also? Suspect I might be missing the point here... Is there some other constraint, perhaps you can't keep them pre sorted?

Comment: I need to be able to locate an element (tuple) in at most O(log n) where n is the number of elements. Perhaps if I kept a search tree where keys are the tuples converted to integers...? I need some comparator for such long numbers then. Also, what if the tuples have arity 100000...0? Actually I suppose it's still fine.

Answer (score 2):

Two options.

Use binary search on a sorted array. If you build the keys ( assuming 32bit int)' with (a<<64)|(b<<32)|c and hold them in a simple array, packed one beside the other, you can use binary search to locate the value you are searching for ( if using C, there is even a library function to do this), and the next one is simply one position along.  Worst case Performance is O(logN), and if you can do http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search then you might even approach O(log log N)

Problem with binary keys is might be tricky to add new values, might need gyrations if you will exceed available memory. But it is fast, only a few random memory accesses on average.

Alternatively, you could build a hash table by generating a key with a|b|c in some form, and then have the hash data pointing to a structure that contains the next value, whatever that might be. Possibly a little harder to create in the first place as when generating the table you need to know the next value already.

Problems with hash approach are it will likely use more memory than binary search method, performance is great if you don't get hash collisions, but then starts to drop off, although there a variations around this algorithm to help in some cases. Hash approach is possibly much easier to insert new values.

I also see you had a similar question along these lines, so I guess the guts of what I am saying is combine A,b,c to produce a single long key, and use that with binary search, hash or even b-tree. If the length of the key is your problem (what language), could you treat it as a string?

If this answer is completely off base, let me know and I will see if I can delete this answer, so you questions remains unanswered rather than a useless answer.

Comment: It's actually a great answer. There are 2 things not clear: 1) What would be the advantage of a B-tree over a, let's say, balanced binary search tree, in this case? (is there one?) 2) I am using Java. What if I used something like BigInteger?I could also compute the key every time it is needed.

Comment: Also, what would be the complexity of comparing the keys?

Comment: The first option is a simple array, not a tree.  Defined thus: struct { int key[3]; data...; } theArray[NNN]; to search you start it the middle NNN/2, then go up or down depending on comparison. When comparing keys, you check key[0], and only need to check key[1] if the values are equal, althougth the examples at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Search/Binary_search in java seem to cover lots of examples.